# Get Control/Form object from IntPtr Handle

Tags: c#, .net, windows, handle, hwnd

I try to get the managed control from a shown Word Application window using following code:

```
Process[] processes = null;
processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("WINWORD");
Process wordProc = processes[0];
Control wordControl = Control.FromHandle(wordProc.MainWindowHandle);
```

unfortunately wordControl is always null... as far as i know, FromHandle returns null, if no handle related control was found. But actually I guess there should be a related control, because I can see the window on my screen.

Therefore my question is, if I'm doing something terribly wrong while trying to get the handle or the control. 
Or maybe my general approach will not work for some, at this time unknown, reasons based somewhere in the .NET / Windows environment.

Comment: actually for your information: MainWindorHandle returns an appropriate handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible. You cannot take an instance of Word running in its own process and cast it as a C# WinForms Control - this would be totally insecure.

Depending on what you want to do, there are two approaches you can take:

- If you want to affect the behaviour of an existing Word instance, then you can send it some messages using SendMessage() and other assorted User32.DLL functions. Use [Pinvoke / DLL Import](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SendMessage) to accomplish this.
- If you are trying to use Word functionality in an app you have written (e.g. create word document) then use [Word interop libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.office.interop.word%28v=office.11%29.aspx):

**Edit**

If you're interested in handling key events in an existing Word instance, you can use a [Low Level keyboard hook](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SetWindowsHookEx) to deal with key events, specifying the handle of the word procs you're interested in.

Comment: thanks Richard. I hoped that this won't be the case but never the less, what I'm actually trying to do is capture the keydown event (winAPI) of an opened Word Document. The code doing this is an add in of word. Do you got some idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to handle any key down events in Word?

Comment: yes. i want to consider every key down - at a first try at least.

Comment: I'm more familiar with VB6 (i.e. COM model) than C#/.Net, but would the IAccessible --> IDispatch --> COM Object --> Named-object-that-has-events-overridden approach have worked? It's allowed me quite a lot of versatility when dealing with out-of-process Office interop...

Answer (score 1):

Control.FromHandle requires you to pass the handle of the managed control, not the MainWindowHandle of the win32 window...

Comment: what means a managed control in this case? I thought the Word application form may be a managed control. But actually, i only got the Handle of the running process - i guess that's not what a managed control is all about, right?